# How do I get the response headers when making GET request with axios and nuxt?

Tags: axios, nuxt.js

I'm trying to get the CSRF Token from my backend. When using `fetch` I can simply go

```
                const response = await fetch(`/account/csrf/`, {
                    credentials: "include",
                });
                
                const data = await response
                let csrfToken = data.headers.get("X-CSRFToken"); // how is this done with axios?
```

I tried

```
const csrfToken = await this.$axios.$get(`/account/csrf/`, {
 /*
 what is the equivalent here? 
 I don't wish to *send* anything to the server, but rather retrieve, so I guess I can't use headers {}
 */
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead to fetch with the `$get()` helper from nuxt module, you can use the raw `get()` method from Axios as below:

```js
const { data, headers } = await this.$axios.get('/account/csrf/', {
  withCredentials: true
});

const csrfToken = headers["X-CSRFToken"];
```

Comment: Great - thanks, didn't know about the `{headers}` part

Comment: Any idea how i can do this with useFetch? https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-fetch